# Material UI v4 is not compatible with React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to design my website with MUI (Material UI).

But I'm unable to install this library, as I get the below error.

```
-npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\משתמש זה\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-26T23_18_57_858Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\משתמש זה\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-26T23_18_57_858Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried force installing with `npm install @material-ui/core --force`
but that didn't work.

Any one has any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

`@material-ui/core` was the package name in v4, which has been outdated since late 2021. Material UI v5 (the current version) is `@mui/material`. You can find the [installation instructions](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) in the Material UI docs.